# need on capturing image from webcam

Tags: java, media, webcam, jmf

I am working on a project where I have to capture images from webcam.I thought of using [LTI-CIVIL](http://lti-civil.org/) api for this purpose. But it does not work on 64-bit os(I tried to run demo programs on windows 7(64-bit), it didn't work).

Please let me know how to make LTI-CIVIL api work with 64-bit os.Or If you know any other API(Open source or at least free) which will work with 64-bit os.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not versed on LTI-CIVIL, but has native implementations (swt and capture dll) for Linux and Mac 64bit but only Windows 32 x86, so try to use a 32bit JRE in Windows x64 in order to link the 32bit dll of LTI-CIVIL. this kind of problems are related to the JRE, not the Windows architecture (32 vs 64).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after i change from Jar 7 to Jar 6 the problem is gone